# Get the absolute position of an element with Selenium web-driver

Tags: java, javascript, dom, selenium-webdriver

I am using a Selenium web-server in Java, in order to automate many web pages.

For example:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));
```

How can I get the absolute position of `element`?

In Javascript, I can get the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` values of any element in the DOM:

```
var element    = document.getElementById("some_id");
var offsetTop  = element.offsetTop;
var offsetLeft = element.offsetLeft;
```

So the first thing that comes to mind is to call the above script with a `JavascriptExecutor`.

But I would like to avoid this. Is there any other way to obtain these values with Selenium?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In Python this would get the offset top of a web element:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('some_id')
offset_top = element.get_attribute('offsetTop')
```

Since both use Selenium then in Java the equivalent would be (untested):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));
int offsetTop = element.getAttribute("offsetTop");
```

Comment: Nice answer, @ficoath. Reference to the [API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `getLocation()` method of `WebElement`? Seems to do what you need...

Here's the API doc for that:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

However, depending on how your site is built, an elements position could depend on the size of the window (check for `style="position:fixed"`), so be careful when trying to validate position...

Comment: Yes! I have tried `getLocation()`, but encountered the exact problem that you are describing! It gives the relative position of the element; I need the absolute position.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. By relative, you mean that it gives you a different result as the element.offsetTop and element.offsetLeft? If the issue is that the position of your element depends on the browser Window size, it's design related...

Comment: Have you tried comparint with WebDriver.Window and use the `getSize()` and `getPosition()`? Maybe some calculation with these values can give you what you need...

Comment: I need the position of the element, absolute within browser Window. Of course it could be relative to the position of the browser on my screen, but that's not my main concern. Given an element that is displayed in the browser, I need to get it's absolute position within the browser window (**even** if this element is within an `iframe`, by the way).

Comment: I don't think it will help. I get (0,0) for some elements that I know are not positioned at the top left corner of anything (except, perhaps, a `div` or an `iframe` or any other element under which they are located).

Comment: That's weird, the API doc tells just the opposite, but well, maybe it's a bug or a not-well documented feature in WebDriver... Have you tried getting the value you need with javascript and filling it in into some `<input type=hidden>` and then reading it out with Selenium? It's a dirty workaround but it should work...

Comment: I'm automating web pages which are not mine, so I cannot add javascript in them... Or if you meant, that I should do it with `JavascriptExecutor`, then as I mentioned in the question - I am trying to avoid this (because, as you said, it's a dirty workaround).